# GROUP BY but SUM of all items

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table for "trips". A trip is organized by a user. A trip can be viewed online by people. A trip can be part of a group of trips. Now, I want to get all trips by group but want to SUM the "views" of a trip at the same time.

```
SELECT *, SUM(tripView) AS views 
FROM trip
WHERE tripGroup != 0
AND tripOrganizerUserId = '1'
GROUP BY tripGroup
```

With this, I get wrong numbers as "views". So how can I, in the query, without making a "SELECT SUM()" in every while-element, sum the views in this query?

Comment: Don't you want a `count` versus a `sum`?

Comment: `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` in the same query is invalid SQL.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: show your table data and desire output

Comment: Probably need to post some sample input and output that capture what you're trying to do, because at least to me it doesn't seem very clear from what's written.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 1):

As axiac points out in his comment, 'select *' and 'group by' in the same SQL statement is actually illegal. However, MySql's parser is broken when it comes to group by and allows it; I have no idea what it actually calculates but it's wrong.

What you need to do is select what it needs to group by. So your SQL would be:

```
SELECT tripGroup, SUM(tripView) AS views 
FROM trip
WHERE tripGroup != 0
AND tripOrganizerUserId = '1'
GROUP BY tripGroup
```

MySql will parse this correctly, and should give you  the answer you expect.

Comment: MySQL's parser is not necessarily broken. The behaviour is documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html and it explains how it worked before 5.7.5: *"a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of `GROUP BY` permits the select list, `HAVING` condition, or `ORDER BY` list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on `GROUP BY` columns. In this case the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want."*.

Comment: I think 'broken' is a convenient shorthand for all of that.

Comment: Strawberry - thanks for the :) and axiac - I didn't know that, thanks for the info!